# Zeroes of a continuous function on a metric space

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

> Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function on a metric space $X$. Let $Z(f)$ be the set of all $p\in X$ such that $f(p)=0$
>
> - $\text{(a)}$ Prove that $Z(f)$ is closed.
> - $\text{(b)}$ Recall that for a set $E \subset X$ the distance from a point to this set is defined as $$h(x)=\inf_{s\in E}d(x,s)$$ Prove that $h$ is uniformly continuous.
> - $\text{(c)}$ Use the previous part to show that for any closed set $E\subset X$ there exist a continuous function $f:X\to\Bbb{R}$ that is $0$ on $E$ and positive elsewhere.

Let $f$ be a continuous real valued function on a metric space $X$. Let $Z(f)$ be 
the set of all $p\in X$ such that $f(p)=0$.
a) Prove that $Z(f)$ is closed.
b) Recall that for a set $E \subset X$ the distance from a point to this set is defined
as
$$h(x)=\inf_{s\in E}d(x,s).$$ 
Prove that $h$ is uniformly continuous.
c) Use the previous part to show that for any closed set $E \subset X$ there exist a
continuous function $f \colon X \to \mathbb R$ that is $0$ on $E$ and positive elsewhere.

For (a), I think the set $\lbrace0 \rbrace$ is a finite set, which means it is a closed set. By the theorem that a mapping $f$ of a metric space $X$ into a metric space $Y$ is continuous if and only if $f^{-1}(C)$ is closed for very closed set $C$ in $Y$,
$Z(f)$ should be also closed. Is this correct?

I'm not sure how to solve b) and c) at all though.
Maybe I can use that  $\lvert h(x)-h(y) \rvert \leqslant \lvert d(x,y)\rvert$?

Could you help me solve this problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer to (a) is fine.

For (b) note that $|h(x)-h(y)|\le d(x,y)$. **EDIT:** The problem statement misses the necessary conditin that $E\ne\emptyset$. With $E=\emptyset$, we would have $h(x)=\infty$ with some good will, but not a real-valued function.

For (c) note that the $h$ defined in (b) has this property: Trivially $h(x)=0$ for $x\in E$; why is $h(x)>0$ for all $x\notin E$? **EDIT:** Note that in the light of (a), the condition that $E$ is closed is necessary. If $E=\emptyset$, we cannot make use of the function in (b), but letting $h(x)=1$ helps.

Comment: Oh actually I added "ㅣh(x)-h(y)ㅣ=<ㅣd(x,y)ㅣ" before you answered my question! I'm now sure how to use this. That's my problem. Any idea?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen you proved (c) for any arbitrary set $E$. We have to prove the result for any closed sets na

Comment: @InfimumMaximum, HINT: lipschitz continuous.

Comment: @nanthini I didn't prove for arbitrary sets, I just gave a hint. An in the light of (a), the set *must* be closed. There is still the "(why?)" for you to think about. Note that $x\notin E$ implies that $x$ is in the *open* set $X\setminus E$.